# How to highlight text while MediaPlayer is playing a sound in Android?

Tags: android, text, media-player, highlight

I want to highlight the text in a TextView as a MediaPlayer plays the pre-recorded sound of the text. (like karaoke) For now, I just want to cover no text at the beginning of the sound and all the text at the end of the sound. (My highlighted text should look like a progress bar.)

I tried `isPlaying()` method of MediaPlayer object, to get the index of text, I calculated the percentage.

My code is below.

```
while(mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
{
  int percentage = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / mediaPlayer.getDuration() * 100;
  int end = text.length() * percentage / 100;
  story.setText("Hello world!", BufferType.SPANNABLE);
  Spannable span = new SpannableString(story.getText());
  text = story.getText().toString();
  span.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFF00FF00), 0, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
  story.setText(span);
}
```

This seems to be blocking the thread because my app freezes. I tried using AsyncTask but failed.

Do you know how do I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

This might be too late to answer but later better than never, you can achieve this by using `Handler` and method `Handler#postDelay`

```
 private val runnable = object : Runnable {
    override fun run() {
        val string = textView.text.toString()
        val span = SpannableString(string)
        val end = textView.length() * percentage / 1000
        span.setSpan(BackgroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
        textView.clearFocus()
        textView.setTextKeepState(span)
        percentage += 1 // to make the percentage increases, you can remove it
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000)
    }

}
```

and Call this method wherever you like

```
 handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000)
```

> DO NOT forget to clear callbacks `handler.removeCallbacks(runnable)`
>    when you leave the activity otherwise you will leak resources.
>
> DO NOT forget to stop the remove the callback when the percentage reaches 100% or this will be running forever or just crash with `NullPointerException`.

Good luck and Happy coding.